# Jackson polymorphism using EXTERNAL_PROPERTY not working with kotlin default value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

```
sealed class Entity
data class Bacteria(val speciesName: String): Entity()
data class Disease(val diseaseId: Long): Entity()

enum class EntityType {
    MY_Bacteria,
    MY_Disease
}

data class MyRequestBody(
  val entityType: EntityType,
  @JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
        property = "entityType",
        defaultImpl = NoClass::class,
        visible = true
  )
  @JsonSubTypes(
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Disease::class, name = "MY_Disease"),
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Bacteria::class, name = "MY_Bacteria")
  )
  val entity: Entity? = null
)
```

Inbound requests are of the type `MyRequestBody` e.g.

```
{
  "entityType": "MY_Bacteria",
  "entity": {
    "speciesName": "E. Coli"
  }
}
```

`entity` can also be missing

```
{
  "entityType": "MY_Disease"
}
```

I'd like to have polymorphism on the `entity` field of `MyRequestBody`. The type is given by the sibling field, `entityType`, which can be "MY_Bacteria" or "MY_Disease" which map to the `Bacteria` and `Disease` classes respectively.

This solution does not seem to work. I keep on getting a 400 with message "Failed to read HTTP message" when `entity` is missing from the request body (it's not using the default value of null).

Comment: do you have `entityType` set as `MY_Disease` or `MY_Bacteria ` in your request ? can you post your request JSON ?

Comment: ^ updated the post

Comment: can you try updating to property? i.e `include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY`

Comment: Yeah works that way (uses the default value when the property is missing from the JSON) but won't work with JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY. Weird.

Comment: Opened an issue here https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2368